# $\text{ }(t, s) \mapsto e^{t \cdot a} e^{s \cdot b} e^{-t \cdot a} e^{-s \cdot b}$ infinitely differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $a, b \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. How do I see that the function$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M_n(\mathbb{R}), \text{ }(t, s) \mapsto e^{t \cdot a} e^{s \cdot b} e^{-t \cdot a} e^{-s \cdot b}$$is differentiable any number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the product rule it suffices for each of the four factors to be infinitely differentiable. Let's consider only $(t,s) \mapsto e^{t \cdot a}$ - the argument is essentially the same for the others. We can see this function as a composition:

$$ \mathbb R^2 \mathop \to_{(t,s) \mapsto t} \mathbb R \mathop \to_{t \mapsto t \cdot a} M_n( \mathbb R)\mathop \to_{\exp} M_n( \mathbb R) $$

The first two of these functions are linear so their second derivatives are zero, and the exponential is defined as a power series and is thus infinitely differentiable. Thus the composition is infinitely differentiable by the chain rule.